# Using keras or tensorflow to train cnn with one output, with two separate datasets each corresponding loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to train a cnn with one output with two datasets. I want to be able to in each batch to feed some data from the first dataset and some data from the second dataset and each dataset has a different corresponding loss function. I've read articles where if the neural network has two heads this is possible, but I'm not sure how to do two datasets with two losses on the same neural network with one output. I would also be open to using pytorch if there are some existing examples.

Answer (score 0):

> Two datasets with two losses on the same neural network with one
>   output.

You can use multiple loss functions if you have multiple outputs. You can use multiple loss function in below scenarios

1. Single Input Multi Output
2. Multi Input Multi Output

Please refer Single Input Multi Output Network:

```
# Convolutional Encoder
input_img = Input(shape=(img_rows, img_cols, 1))
conv_1 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
pool_1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(conv_1)
conv_2 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool_1)
pool_2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(conv_2)
conv_3 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool_2)
encoded= MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(conv_3)

# Classification
flatten = Flatten()(encoded)
fc = Dense(128, activation='relu')(flatten)
Output1 = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax', name='classification')(fc)

# Decoder
conv_4 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
up_1 = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(conv_4)
conv_5 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up_1)
up_2 = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(conv_5)
conv_6 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu')(up_2)
up_3 = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(conv_6)
Output2 = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same', name='autoencoder')(up_3)

model = Model(inputs=input_img, outputs=[Output1 , Output2])

model.compile(loss={'classification': 'categorical_crossentropy', 
                    'autoencoder': 'binary_crossentropy'},
              loss_weights={'classification': 1.0,
                            'autoencoder': 0.5},
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics={'classification': 'accuracy', 'autoencoder': ['mse']})

model.fit(x_train, 
          {'classification': y_train, 'autoencoder': y_train},
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          validation_data= (x_test, {'classification': y_test, 'autoencoder': y_test}),
          verbose=1)
```

Please refer Multi Input Multi Output Network:

```
main_input = Input(shape=(100,), dtype='int32', name='main_input')
x = Embedding(output_dim=512, input_dim=10000, input_length=100)(main_input)
lstm_out = LSTM(32)(x)

auxiliary_output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='aux_output')(lstm_out)

auxiliary_input = Input(shape=(5,), name='aux_input')
x = keras.layers.concatenate([lstm_out, auxiliary_input])

x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)

main_output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='main_output')(x)

model = Model(inputs=[main_input, auxiliary_input], outputs=[main_output, auxiliary_output])


model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss={'main_output': 'binary_crossentropy', 'aux_output': 'binary_crossentropy'},
              loss_weights={'main_output': 1., 'aux_output': 0.2})


model.fit({'main_input': headline_data, 'aux_input': additional_data},
          {'main_output': headline_labels, 'aux_output': additional_labels},
          epochs=50, batch_size=32)
```

For more information please refer this [link](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models)